# How to maintain a specific number of processes running?

Tags: shell, shell-script, parallelism

I'm trying to write a shell script for converting a lot of .wav files to .mp3. I use the "find" command to find them, then the "lame" command to convert. I can use a simple for loop for this but I need to do this using several parallel processes.

I want to have a defined number of processes, for example 4. Start converting a file in each process. When one file finishes converting in one process, I substitute it with the next file. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest passing the list to `xargs` and use the `-n` and/or `-P` options to control how many processes are running at any given time.

Answer (score 2):

`make` can be good for this.  You'll need a `Makefile` with something like

```
%.mp3: %.wav
lame $(LAMEOPTS) $< $@
```

Then generate a list of targets:

```
$ find . -name '*.wav' -type f | sed -e 's/\(.*\.\)wav$/all: \1mp3/' >>Makefile
```

Now, tell `make` to schedule the tasks:

```
$ make -r -j4 -f Makefile
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned GNU parallel yet. Using it, the command would be as simple as:

```
find -type f -name '*.wav' -print0 | parallel -0 lame {} {.}.mp3
```

This asks to replace each input file's extension with `mp3`. By default, parallel will run as many jobs as there are CPUs on the machine, but you can set a different value with `-j <i>integer</i>`. The switch --dry-run can be useful to see which commands would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `xjobs` installed, you'll find that this is exactly the kind of task it's designed for.  In particular, check the description of the `-j` option to tune how many processes are created.